# Spring gives RESTful WS implementation OR only a wrapper over implementations

Tags: spring, rest

Spring gives RESTful Web Service implementation or provides only a wrapper to implementations like jersey,etc.

I am asking this question, as I have NOT see this nature in some of the POC codes on internet.
But heard and read a lot that Spring is all about wrappers (apart from IOContainer and AOP) like HibernateTransactionManager

Edit : 1st Dec'14
All in all, what I want to understand is : who will going to give the implementation for annotations like @RequestMapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's REST implementation is independent from other implementations. It is based on Spring MVC with some additional annotations. Note however that it is not an JAX-RS protocol implementation like frameworks like Jersey, Apache CXF and RESTEasy are.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. can you please elaborate on 'some additional annotation', are the implementation of these are given in spring-mvc lib(jar)

Comment: yes, the implementation is in spring mvc, in fact, the rest documentation is included in the spring mvc documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html. It describes using ResponseBody annotation to make your method return rest response, or just using RestController instead of Controller annotation (RestController combines Controller with ResponseBody annotations so that if all your methods in controller are restful, you don't have to specify ResponseBody annotation to everyone)